# titles appearing in collectionview when scroll up/down

Tags: ios, json, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

when app run, titles(label in collectionview) are not appearing. scrolling up or down then titles are appearing. Also in numberOfItemsInSection,[news count] result is 0.

fffdgdfgdfghfghgfhgfhgghghhgjgjghjghjh

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    NSLog(@"viewDidLoad ");
    [super viewDidLoad];
    leftMenu.target=self.revealViewController;
    leftMenu.action=@selector(revealToggle:);
    self.title=@"Main";
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:self.revealViewController.panGestureRecognizer];


    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=YES;
    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.test.com/ios/GetMainInfoByCat.php?cat_id=76"];
    NSURLRequest *request=[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

    //self.collectionview.dataSource=self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
    data=[[NSMutableData alloc]init];
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)Thedata
{
    [data appendData:Thedata];
}
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading ");
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

    dnews=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    news=[dnews objectForKey:@"news_main_info_by_cat"];
    NSString *str=[news valueForKey:@"img_url"];

    //[self.collectionview reloadData];
    //NSLog(@"%@",str);
}
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    UIAlertView *erroMsg=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Qoşula bilmədi. İnternet bağlantınızı yoxlayın" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Dismiss" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [erroMsg show];
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    [collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger) collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"%i",[news count]);
    [collectionView.collectionViewLayout invalidateLayout];
    return 10;
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell=(UICollectionView *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.newsTitle.text=[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"post_title"];
    //cell.newsImage.image=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"img_url"]]];
    //[[news objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"img_url"];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Make sure you are calling reloadData method from mainThread

Comment: So you should reload again when you got the data and make sure you are doing from main thread if you are loading ur data in background

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call reloadData

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"connectionDidFinishLoading ");
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible=NO;

    dnews=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    news=[dnews objectForKey:@"news_main_info_by_cat"];
    NSString *str=[news valueForKey:@"img_url"];

    [self.collectionview reloadData];
}
```

**Update**: make sure IBoutlet is connected to collectionView

Comment: called this in connectionDidFinishLoading. nothing changed. i tried it before `[self.collectionview reloadData];`

Comment: it you are using an iBOUtlet make sure collectionView is connected with collectionView and can print out and see if news have items

Comment: Thank you. working. there is problem with IBOutlet and collectionview connection

Answer (score 0):

--> When you are scrolling collectionview or tableview at that time they are reloading the data so that when you are get your array after that please reload your scroll view this will sure help you.

Comment: when i add this code to viewDidLoad, getting error `dnews=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
    news=[dnews objectForKey:@"news_main_info_by_cat"];
    NSString *str=[news valueForKey:@"img_url"];`

Comment: reload your collectionview at "connection didfinishloading" in last line. in viewdidload your news array didn't filled out that's why you getting error.

Comment: callied this in connectionDidFinishLoading. nothing changed. i tried it before`[self.collectionview reloadData];`